# Youtube-dl KeyError: 'entries'

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl, keyerror

I tried to get some infos of a video with discord.py when "+dl https://youtube......" is executed, the program download in mp3 the youtube link and send it with : video name, duration and id but i get an error during execution :

```
    ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': './SomethingMore/dl.mp3',
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'noplaylist': True,
    'default_search' : 'ytsearch',
    'postprocessors': [{
    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'preferredquality': '192',
    }]}

    Link = ctx.message.content
    Link = Link.strip('+dl ')

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:

        playlist_dict = ydl.extract_info(Link, download=False)
        
        for video in playlist_dict['entries']:
                 
            if not video:
                print('ERROR: Unable to get info. Continuing...')
                continue
 
            video_title = video.get("title")
            video_duration = video.get("duration")
            video_id = video.get("id")
            

        await ctx.channel.send('Download of '+ video_title +' is starting, please wait a minute')

        try:
            ydl.download([Link])
            await ctx.channel.send('Download ended')
```

Here is the error :

```
Ignoring exception in command dl:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zarcross\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "h:\Users\Zarcross\Desktop\Discord\main.py", line 267, in dl
    for video in playlist_dict['entries']:
KeyError: 'entries'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zarcross\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Zarcross\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zarcross\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'entries'
```

Comment: " but i get an error during execution :" Please show the [*complete* error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: Also, please try to make a properly-contained, [minimal example](http://sscce.org). Are you able to make the process work outside the context of your Discord bot? If no, then the problem has nothing to do with your Discord bot, and therefore nothing to do with `discord.py`; so you shouldn't show us that part (you should instead show us only your minimal example), and you shouldn't tag it that way. If yes, then the problem is with how your bot interfaces to that, and we need more context.

Comment: You should also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . For example, did you try to verify that `Link` looks like what you expect? How about `playlist_dict`? If there was a discrepancy, did you try to find a reason for that?

Comment: My link is the good link, I get https://youtu.be/......

Comment: Same probleme without discord.py

Comment: Okay, so we have learned two things: first, you should be able to produce an example that is only using the YDL code, and second, that `playlist_dict` doesn't contain what you expect it to contain. You say the link is good, but does it actually link to a playlist (rather than a specific video)?

Comment: Link actually link a specific video, not a playlist, but how can i do to make a thing like a  "video_dict" because the problem is the "playlist_dict" isn't it ?

Comment: Well, if it's a video and not a playlist, then what are you expecting the "entries" to contain? If it's a single video, then why do you figure on having a loop to iterate `for video in` something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your `playlist_dict` doesn't have key `'entries'`.

It is hard to say, why. Try checking what you still have in `playlist_dict`.

Beside of that, it's a bad practice to mix blocking (`youtube-dl`) and asynchronous (`ctx.channel.send()`)  code together.

Consider scheduling blocking calls from a separate thread (`asyncio.to_thread()`)

---

UPD: As far as I can see, now `YoutubeDL.extract_info()` just returns list of dicts, so you can remove `['entries']` part and just iterate over the returned list.

```py
In [73]: import youtube_dl as ydl

In [74]: with ydl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    ...:     ydl.extract_info??
    ...:
Signature:
ydl.extract_info(
    url,
    download=True,
    ie_key=None,
    extra_info={},
    process=True,
    force_generic_extractor=False,
)
Source:
    def extract_info(self, url, download=True, ie_key=None, extra_info={},
                     process=True, force_generic_extractor=False):
        '''
        Returns a list with a dictionary for each video we find.
        If 'download', also downloads the videos.
        extra_info is a dict containing the extra values to add to each result
        '''

        if not ie_key and force_generic_extractor:
            ie_key = 'Generic'

        if ie_key:
            ies = [self.get_info_extractor(ie_key)]
        else:
            ies = self._ies

        for ie in ies:
            if not ie.suitable(url):
                continue

            ie = self.get_info_extractor(ie.ie_key())
            if not ie.working():
                self.report_warning('The program functionality for this site has been marked as broken, '
                                    'and will probably not work.')

            return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
        else:
            self.report_error('no suitable InfoExtractor for URL %s' % url)
File:      ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py
Type:      method
```

Comment: I understand, but in a classic play command who a song is downloaded too with same parameters, it works and here, it's not working. I don't really know what is 'entries'

Comment: Okay, like this it works, thanks you a lot